# Is there a way to make Cabal print test cases in real time?

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I use stack locally with test suite (Hspec), it prints tests cases
(their names, contexts) in real time. Now I need to force this behavior on
Travis CI (where I use Cabal) because my test suite has begun to take
longer than 10 minutes and I end up with:

> No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially
>   indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.

Tried `--show-details=streaming` without success (also in combination with
`--test-option=--format=progress`).

---

Commands that are executed (a variant):

```
cabal install --only-dependencies --enable-tests
cabal configure --enable-tests --enable-coverage -v2
cabal build
cabal test --show-details=streaming --test-option=--format=progress
```

Comment: Please post your cabal file and the exact command that Travis is running.

Comment: @WillSewell, Added commands that are run on the CI server. What do you expect to figure out from cabal file?

Comment: Travis can work with stack, btw.

Comment: @PyRulez, Of course it can, but I need make sure it builds even with Cabal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't compiling your program with the `-threaded` flag. This is required, otherwise it will behave as if you had set `--show-details=always`, even if you had set `--show-details=streaming`.

The reason I wanted to look at your cabal file is you might have set `-threaded` there.

Comment: No way. It doesn't work for me. Results are printed only when entire test suite finishes.

Comment: Where did you set the `-threaded` flag? And what do you see if you run the same commands that are run on Travis locally?

Comment: In `ghc-options: -threaded` in cabal file, test suite section. This may be just something related to Travis, maybe it has something to do with buffering, I don't know. To test this locally I need to setup the whole sandbox thing. I will do this if `travis_wait` does not work for me. This problem has already caused painful delay in my work, so if `travis_wait` works out, I won't spend any extra minute thinking what's wrong with Cabal this time, enough of this hairy stuff. I accept your answer, I think it's correct in general.

Comment: Thanks. `travis_wait` should do it, but it's a shame that it doesn't fix the root of the problem. I think the only way to narrow it down further would be to try and reproduce it locally. Good luck.